# Custom Content Block SDK Icons

Tags: marketing-cloud

What are the sizes of the block icon and the dragging icon? The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/develop-block-widget.htm) doesn't specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine with 60x60 px.
For dragIcon this is verified (it's the image in the left toolbar to drag and drop icons onto the canvas.).

Not 100% sure on the usage of the blockIcon. In our project we used 60x60 for both.

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate it!